# UITableView tableHeaderView autolayout programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I want to add layout constraint to `tableHeaderView`

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; // THIS WILL CRASH
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;

UIView *headerWrapperView = [[UIView alloc] init];
headerWrapperView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
headerWrapperView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[headerView addSubview:headerWrapperView];

NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[headerWrapperView]-10-|"
               options:0
               metrics:nil
               views:viewsDictionary];
[headerView addConstraints:constraints];
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-10-[headerWrapperView]-10-|"
               options:0
               metrics:nil
               views:viewsDictionary];
[headerView addConstraints:constraints];
```

If I remove `headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` this line,
then I get

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797f54f0 H:|-(20)-[UITextField:0x797ed440]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x797ea9e0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797f5540 H:[UITextField:0x797ed440]-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x797ea9e0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797f5270 H:|-(10)-[UIView:0x797ea9e0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x797ea800 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797f52e0 H:[UIView:0x797ea9e0]-(10)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x797ea800 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x79729910 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x797ea800(0)]>"
)
```

Has anyone resolve this issue? Can provide example?

**P/S: There are other views inside `headerWrapperView`**

### Update

I try using non-autolayout for `headerView` and all it's subview, `tableView` remain autolayout

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 400)];
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;

NSLog(@"headerView %@", headerView);
```

Then I get this result

`headerView <UIView: 0x79c38430; frame = (0 0; 0 400); layer = <CALayer: 0x79c38490>>`

If without this line *(line below)*

```
_tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

then I get

`headerView <UIView: 0x79c38430; frame = (0 0; 320 400); layer = <CALayer: 0x79c38490>>`

Answer (score 0):

from this error report

NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x79729910 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x797ea800(0)]

I think if you remove that line, the width of that view is 0

try to init that view with a frame CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 300)

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
 self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

[self.view addConstraints:@[
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0],

```
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:0],

         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0],

         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0],
     ]];
```

///it's important

```
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.topV;
     });
```

}